# Cordova: Cant add android platform on windows 8

Tags: android, windows, node.js, batch-file, cordova

i have developed android applications in linux and wanted to try developing it on other platform like windows. i have installed all the necessary files (node.js, ADT bundle for windows, cordova, phonegap) and have it all running. i can create a project via windows command line. an example project ive made is: cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld. the project was created successfully. then, got to the destination of the project to add android platform with command: cordova -d platform add android. error then came saying,

```
'C:\Users\My' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Command finished with error code 1: C:\Users\My user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat --cli,C:\Users\My user\Documents\Android Development\Workspace\hello\platforms\android,com.example.hello,HelloWorld Error: C:\Users\My user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 1 Command failed with exit code 1 at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\superspawn.js:126:23) at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17) at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

i dont know what to do. please if you know or you have an idea. post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a missing quote issue. The folder where you put your project contains spaces and maybe somewhere in the build sctipt the path misses some quotes.

The fastest way to solve your issue would be to put your project somewhere else.

Comment: i have no idea how did it really worked but thank you. i changed the project location. now im getting 'ant' problem. ive set my path but it says i ddnt.