# command cordova platform add android not recognized internal or external command?

Tags: android, eclipse, node.js, cordova, ant

I did all Pre-requests steps for creating phonegap android apps. I installed all things like a

- Installing Apache ANT
- Installing Eclipse
- Adding Android ADT Plugin
- Installing NodeJS
- Installing Cordova
- Setting up Environment Variable

but when I was fire the command like **cordova platform add android** then I got following screen 
[image]

before this command all commands worked properly. please anybody tell me how to solve this problem..
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you just write cordova platform add android? or C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\DesignTechCadAcadamy>cordova platform add android?

Comment: I wrote like a C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\DesignTechCadAcadamy>cordova platform add android.. please see the command prompt image

Comment: you only have to write "cordova platform add android"

Comment: you mean to say just write C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>cordova platform add android

Comment: no, I mean just write cordova platform add android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156317/cordova-cant-add-android-platform-on-windows-8/23156512#23156512), it seems cordova cli does not work correctly if you have spaces in the folder where you put your project.

Most people (including me) using windows 7 or 8 don't have the issue because "c:\Documents and Settings" has been replaced by "c:\Users".

Which version of cordova are you using? (I don't seem to be able to reproduce the issue with cordova 3.4.1)

I see two solutions for you (plus upgrading to latest cordova if you have a older version) :

### 1)Use folder's short name:

```
cd c:\Docume~1\Administrator\DesignTechCadAcadamy
cordova platform add android
```

### or 2)Try to create a folder at the root of your disk and work in this folder instead of in your user's folder.

For example try

```
md c:\CordovaProjects
pushd c:\CordovaProjects
cordova create test
cd test
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Just a note for those that are using Windows 7/8 and see this issue; if your user name has a space, it falls under the same problem (ex. "C:\Users\John Everyman\.cordova\"). It still seems to be an issue in Cordova 3.5.0.